# Node.JS как получить размер прикмаунченой папки?

Tags: linux, node.js, веб-программирование, sftp

Есть сервер на Ubuntu 18.04 и сервер на Windows Server 2008 R2
На Linux сервере прикручены шары из Win сервера.

При попытке использовать ssh2 и вывести список всего из директории, через SFTP подключение, размер папок которые физически не находятся на Linux сервере не определяется.

Может есть что то что корректно может определять размер на папок?

Comment: размер папок вроде только по файлам самому посчитать можно. у папки нет такого свойства как размер.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev файлов достаточно много 500-10000 и общий размер может доходить до 100ГБ. Я не сильно понимаю, пересчет такого количества может быть долгим

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev ошибался, попробовал считать файлы, все быстро. Спасибо.